# Downloading movies from TiVo Series 3 HD Recorder to Mac OS X

Tags: video, data-transfer, file-transfer

I have a TiVo Series 3 HD Recorder purchased in Dec 2006. For the past few years, when I have wanted to archive something from the TiVo to my Macintosh, I used [iTiVo](http://code.google.com/p/itivo/). However, this application has many issues (crashes, freezes, very, very slow) and has not been updated in almost 2 years. My frustration with its "quirks" has prompted me to seek another solution. The only other Macintosh OS X software I have found via google is a Dashboard Widget (ick) called [TiVo NowPlaying](http://www.dashboardwidgets.com/showcase/details.php?wid=281). This widget (versioned 2.51) has not been updated since Oct 2007. It's usable, but not ideal (slow, sometimes needs to be restarted and doesn't support mpeg4).

I am using fairly modern Macintosh (intel) computers, updated to the current version of Mac OS X (Snow Leopard).

**What are other Macintosh + TiVo owners using to move content from their TiVo to the Macintosh**?

I am hoping someone has some information on something better to use than the options I have listed above.

Answer (score 1):

kmttg is a cross-platform Java program that does what you're looking for.  Personally I've used it on Windows without issue to copy shows off my Tivo onto my computer, do a batch convert of the video files, along with batch rename.  It's a very powerful and handy tool for any owner of a Tivo Series 3 or more recent Tivo.   It should run on modern Macs without issue.

You can grab it off Google Code [here](http://code.google.com/p/kmttg/).  The Tivo Community forums have an *extremely* long-running thread about the tool [here](http://www.tivocommunity.com/tivo-vb/showthread.php?t=387725).